# How to route a program through HTTP proxy on linux

Tags: linux, http, ubuntu, proxy, global

I am working on ubuntu machine behind an institute's HTTP proxy which requires username:password authentication. There are some programs like rubygem installer(gem install *) which have very poor way of proxy handling.

How to reroute that through a proxy program so that I don't have to use proxy in rubygems(or similar) program? A very similar example of what I am talking about is Proxifier on Windows.

What I have tried so far : 
1. Setting proxy in the program ( works, but very poor proxy handling of the particular program)
2. Set environment proxy variable. (didn't work)
3. Use proxychains. (perhaps to complicated and does not work on single HTTP proxy.)
4. Searching on web. (Searched a lot. Didn't find any satisfactory solution)

P.S. Rubygems is just an example. There are lot many programs I use have such problem.

Comment: Proxychains doesn't work on a single HTTP proxy? [citation-needed], I've used it succesfully just for that. Perhaps the "too complicated" part is the problem here...? What problems exactly do you have there?

Comment: in proxychains.conf, I have added the line at end
`http ip.of.my.proxy port username password`

when I use it I get the error that the DNS(which i will be accessing through proxy does not exist)
I have also tried with root... same problem

Comment: @Piskvor : here's a link to my proxychains.conf file... Perhaps you could figure out the error. [link](http://home.iitb.ac.in/~amol_mandhane/proxychains.conf)